# I am able to create a function but unable to call it

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a function in postgres, CREATE query successfully executed but when i try to invoke the function, i am getting error.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_generate_random_locations(
 "nwclatitude" NUMERIC,
 "nwclongitude" NUMERIC,
 "seclatitude" NUMERIC,
 "seclongitude" NUMERIC,
 "type" TEXT,
 "count" INTEGER,
 "runid" TEXT
 ) RETURNS INT AS
 $BODY$
 DECLARE
 counter INTEGER := 0 ; 
 id uuid := uuid_generate_v1();
 responder_latitude FLOAT(5):= nwclatitude+(seclatitudenwclatitude)*RANDOM();
 responder_longitude FLOAT(5):= nwclongitude+(seclongitudenwclongitude)*RANDOM();
 BEGIN
 LOOP
 EXIT WHEN counter=count;
--some task
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
SECURITY DEFINER 
SET search_path = admin, pg_temp;
```

And now if i try to call the function with the below command

```
SELECT aed_modeling.sp_generate_random_locations(“nwclatitude” := 54.42 ,”nwclongitude” := 10.05 ,”seclatitude” := 54.14, “seclongitude” := 10.48,”type” :=’mobile’ ,”count” :=4 ,”runid” := ‘94984cb0-5f69-4326-b492-34fb19c39fc3’);
```

But i am getting the below error

```
42883: function sp_generate_random_locations(“nwclatitude” => numeric, ”nwclongitude” => numeric, ”seclatitude” => numeric, “seclongitude” => numeric, ”type” => unknown, ”count” => integer, ”runid” => unknown) does not exist
```

I don't know what i am missing here. Please note "runid" used is not a uuid, i am using it as a string. even if i type cast the variables "type" and "runid" with `::text` also it does not work.

Comment: have tried  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aed_modeling.sp_generate_random_locations (without the schema it will be created in public)?

Comment: `“nwclatitude” := 54.42` should be `"nwclatitude" := 54.42` (`"`instead of `“` or `”`). Actually you don't need those dreaded double quotes at all. The best solution is to remove all of them. But if you insist on using them, use the correct straight `"` double quotes, not the typographical ones.

Comment: Yes, the problem is probably the incorrect use of `”` and `’` instead of `"` and `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late response, yes as per the comments the problem was with incorrect double quotes. Copy paste issues. :-D

E.g. `“nwclatitude” := 54.42 should be "nwclatitude" := 54.42`